# Zoom tool windows on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

How do you zoom the tool windows (E.g. Solution Explorer, GIT explorer and so on)? My eyes are getting older and those windows are just too small to see comfortably. I know about the zoom in the text editor already. That isn't what I am looking for. I am using VS2022 and VS2019.

Any options for this?

Comment: Ought to be an issue with text in any program.  In Win10 use Settings > System > Display, "Change the size of text..."

Comment: I think it just bothers me in Visual Studio so much because that is where I spend most of my time. I try to only take brief, passing glances at my email :)

Comment: @MikeDice I am asking because I have the same problem and want to check if I'm missing something. Hans's method affects EVERYTHING, including VS. Why would you wish to change ONLY VS?

Answer (score 4):

Try going under Tools / Options / Environment / Fonts and Colors / Environment and set the font size there.

[image]

Comment: That is partially the answer. I wanted to keep the same font it is using now, just make it bigger. My setting for that value was 'Automatic'. I came to learn that 'Automatic' means use the system font and then I had to go find that the system font was set to Segoe UI. So then, I could use your answer: set the font to Segoe UI and make its size bigger. Thanks for your help. My eyes are more comfortable now.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using VS2022 and there is a Zoom to the lower left of the screen.
It should be on the bar that displays your LN: CH: SPC  CRLF

I don't know if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I tried Settings > System > Display, "Change the size of text..." to 150% and the display went wild.  The mouse didn't line up with anything, the hidden task bar would pop up with the mouse 3 inches from the screen bottom, the calendar popped up for no reason.  It was a real struggle to get it back to 100%.  Another Windoze 10 Easter Egg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).